# Why does local sigma escape its Block in Mathematica 13.0.1?

Tags: front-end, scoping, symbols, traditional-form

My objective is to utilize Traditional Form in .NB files.  But I've run into a problem where variables I intend to be local to a Block "escape" with an assigned value causing unexpected & unwanted side effects in subsequent pipeline processing.

Copy the following code into a .NB file to see the unexpected "escape" and please help me with the following two questions:

1. Why did sigma variable "escape" its Block with an assigned value; and
2. Would the new Notation package solve this unexpected "escape" of a local variable sigma?

---

Sample Data

```
data = Dataset @{<|"M" -> 101, "\[Beta]" -> 1|>, <|"M" -> 108, 
     "\[Beta]" -> 1|>, <|"M" -> 100, "\[Beta]" -> 4|>, <|"M" -> 112, 
     "\[Beta]" -> 3|>};
```

Traditional Form Accessor function

```
(Subscript[#, j_] := 
     data[j, ToString@# ] // Normal) & /@ {M, \[Beta]} ;

(* Verify: Accessor works as expected *)

{Subscript[M, #], 
    Subscript[\[Beta], #]} & /@ Range @ Length @ data // TableForm
```

All symbols within the following Block are expected to be local; none should survive outside the Block

```
sigmaEscape[dataset_Dataset] := 
  Block[{\[Sigma], M, \[Beta], M\[Beta] , k},
   k = Length @ dataset;
   Subscript[\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(M\), \(^\)]\), ❊] = dataset[Mean, "M"];
   Subscript[\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(\[Beta]\), \(^\)]\), ❊] = dataset[Mean, "\[Beta]"];
   
   Subscript[\[Sigma], M\[Beta]] = \!\(\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(i = 1\), \(k\)]\*FractionBox[\(\((\*SubscriptBox[\(M\), \(i\)]\  - \ \*SubscriptBox[OverscriptBox[\(M\), \(^\)], \(❊\)])\) \((\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Beta]\), \(i\)]\  - \ \*SubscriptBox[OverscriptBox[\(\[Beta]\), \(^\)], \(❊\)])\)\), \(k\  - \ 1\)]\)];
```

Per the following test, the sigma subscripted local variable has an assigned value outside the Block -- how?!

````
If[sigmaEscape @ data == Subscript[\[Sigma], M\[Beta]]
    , "How did \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Sigma]\), \\(M\[Beta]\)]\) \"escape\" the block with an assigned value?!"]

 ```
````

Comment: Block `Subscript` instead of `\[Sigma]`

Comment: NOTE: Block[{Subscript[\[Sigma], M\[Beta]]}, ...] is rejected as an error by the FrontEnd.

Comment: I said instead! In other words, `Block[{Subscript}, ...]`

Comment: Carl -- thank you!  I'm not exactly clear on why a local over-ride on Subscript fixes the issue, but I'll take that quick fix to steam on with my work!